# PHP timezone Etc/GMT+5 becomes -0500?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

As with many web apps, the app I'm developing needs to work with converting timezones for our dear end users. However, as I worked with Carbon / DateTime in PHP 5.3, I found this weird:

```
$date_str = '2014-04-15 12:00:00'; // from database

$date = new DateTime($date_str,new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Etc/GMT+5'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O'); // 2014-04-15 07:00:00 -0500
```

I set the `$date`'s timezone to GMT+5, but when I format the `$date`, it becomes `-0500` instead of the expected `+0500`.

Likewise if I set it to negative, i.e. `Etc/GMT-5`, the format shows `+0500` instead of the expected `-0500`.

Anyone able to enlighten?

I was able to replicate this problem in PHP 5.3.3, 5.3.13, 5.3.28. Thought it was a PHP-specific-version bug. A bug or feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting case. The `Etc/GMT` timezones have their sign reversed.

From the [Wikipedia article on *tz database*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area):

> In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names beginning with `Etc/GMT` have their sign reversed from what most people expect. In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g `Etc/GMT-14` is 14 hours ahead/east of GMT.)

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) also warns you not to use this timezone:

> **Warning:** Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.

---

Instead of using an offset, use a specific timezone identifier. To get a list of valid timezones, you can use `print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL));`.

Comment: `new DateTimeZone('GMT+5')` throws `Unknown or bad timezone (GMT+5)` exception. But thanks for the explanation on the *tz database*!

Comment: @mauris: Works on my local system, don't know why. I feel this is not the right approach. Either way, instead of using an offset, try using a specific timezone. That might work.

Comment: I will proceed to store the timezone identifier e.g. "Europe/London" in my database setup for conversion then. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

i hope it help you

just remove

etc/gmt

with gtm+offset

```
$date_str = '2014-04-15 12:00:00'; // from database

$date = new DateTime($date_str,new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT+5'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
```

Output    2014-04-15 17:00:00 +0500